# Desire2Learn Put GradeObject Shortname Bug?

Tags: desire2learn

I believe that the put GradeObject Put api call has a bug when trying to update the ShortName field.

I believe that the ShortName is not being updated (other fields appear updated correctly). The Post new grade object works as expected.

I am receiving a 200 result, and fields are updated as expected, however, the ShortName is not being updated.
The response I receive contains the correct ShortName (ie the one that I passed and would expect D2L to change to), but it's not updated on D2L.

We use the same Grade object to Add (Post) as we do to (Push), so we are interested in your thoughts.

I can confirm that I am using the same spelling and case as documented here: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html

I can also confirm that the SAME OBJECT works correctly when 'posting' the object, only put fails to update that field, and it's only that field that doesn't get updated.

Is this a D2L Bug?
Can somebody from D2L or otherwise confirm that updating the Shortname works as expected?

Comment: Hi Steve -- can you please let us know what version of the LMS you're using to make the API calls against? It's possible this was a known defect that was fixed since the version you're using, or that it's a known defect that's destined for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Valence Learning Framework API's GradeObject update APIs. It has not yet been addressed.

Currently, there is no way through the APIs to set or update the `ShortName` property of a grade object.